# Different ways to pronounce "r?"

Tags: prononciation

I noticed that "r" in "merveilleux" is pronounced differently than a normal "r," which is somewhat similar to [the end of the English word "ugh"](http://www.memrise.com/course/691338/a1-french/8/garden/preview/).

It sounds rather like the Spanish "r," which involves trilling the tip of your tongue. Does this happen a lot generally or only in careful speech, e.g. when demonstrating pronunciation?

Comment: as Eria said, I don't feel a different "r" while pronouncing "merveilleux". Where did you hear it ? We cannot go to your link since a subscription is required

Comment: I don't think I pronounce the "r" in "merveilleux" the way you describe it. Did you ear it from a native french speaker ?

Comment: Consonant  /R/  is prone to regional variations  - within France and also of course among French speaking countries.

Answer (score 3):

The "r" in "merveilleux" is no different than the one in "merci" or "partir", it sounds short and is not as rolled as the spanish r.
However, some may intentionally say the first part of words in a long and toned voice to express joy (used in theaters mostly)

e.g: "Mais c'est meeerrveilleux".

Overall, no the r in merveilleux, if said normally, is not any different.

Answer (score 1):

I listened to the Memrise recording from the link, and I don't think the r is rolled like it is in Spanish in the recording - it is just the throat sound made when you make the r sound in French. The r sound in merveilleux is the same as any other r sound.